# Validate documents during CouchDB replication process

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

During replication, I need to validate documents that a client tries to write to my CouchDB instance. Ideally, I should reject just "invalid" documents allowing all others to pass through. Other possible outcome might be to reject the whole replication process and do not accept any documents altogether. I cannot use the `validate_doc_update` function because it lacks all the necessary information to make a decision.

I thought about serving all [endpoints needed for replication](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/protocol.html#for-target) behind the service and validate docs on an application level. For example, take all docs from `POST /_bulk_docs` and send back 400 error response if some docs are invalid.

Do I understand it right that such an approach stops the replication process, and the database might be left with partially replicated documents? It's because [documents are uploaded in chunks](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/protocol.html#replicate-changes) during replication, and therefore there are might be couple `POST /_bulk_docs` calls where the first one has all valid docs and second invalid.

Is there another way, how can I discard only invalid docs?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a Cloudant Query selector via your replication document to specify which documents are valid. The canonical example is to ditch tombstones:

```
{
    "_id": "repl01",
    "source" : "https://.../<source>",
    "target" : "https://.../<target>",
    "selector": {
        "_deleted": {
            "$exists": false
        }
    }
}
```

See https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-replication-api#the-selector-field for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did not know about that part. I'm considering a situation when a malicious client runs the replication process and tries to write invalid docs to my DB; as far as I understand in this situation, 'selector' won't help since client can just ignore it during the replication.